# Pound (£) and euro (€) signs encoded wrong in external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, urlencode, encode, url-encoding

I'm trying to encode the £ sign in an external JS file but I keep getting '%EF%BF%BD'. Here's the code in its simplicity:

```
alert(encodeURIComponent("£"));
```

The same alert gives me '%C2%A3' on the HTML page that is calling the external JavaScript file. The HTML page has the following character set:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And I've defined the character set for the external JS file too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

How can I force the external JavaScript file use UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, it would benefit from a jsfiddle that demonstrates the precise problem.

Comment: I can't demonstrate it in jsfiddle because the problem is with character encoding in my JS file - when I test it in jsfiddle (or have the JS code in my HTML file) it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the problem by creating a blank JS file with UTF-8 encoding, copying the code in from the original file and replacing the old file with the new file.

Comment: Not something we could have answered for you, glad you solved it. Don't forget to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ef bf bd` is the [replacement character](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65280) - what a browser uses if it does not have the given character in its font.

If it renders correctly here, it looks like this: �

My guess would be that whatever font you're using does not support the British pound symbol £

Could you add a link to the page you're using or a demo?

Comment: Sadly I can't send a link as it's a commercial project I'm working on but I can confirm that I'm getting the � symbol if I for example write the character in an input box. I'm not sure how font is related to this though because I'm not writing it on the page, it's wrong in the alert alone.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UTF encoded](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a3/index.htm) character

```
alert("\u00A3");
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/cxB5t/)

UPDATE: I am still unsure as to what your problem is, but here is a further example.

HTML

```
<div id="out"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var link = "http://somewhere.com",
    tweet = "£££££€€€€€€€",
    x = '<a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(tweet) + '">anchor</a>';

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = x;

alert(decodeURIComponent(x));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/5bBry/)

As I suggested in the comments, you should construct a jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue you are having if the above is not the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: The example above is simplified to show £ sign only but in reality I'm trying to encode a whole sentence that may contain a number of special characters, for example: encodeURIComponent("The cost of x is £20 and cost of y is £10 - same in euros is €30 and €15.")

Comment: And where and how do you want to display it? In HTML web page or alert? It is very unclear what you are trying to achieve, or what the source is.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript to generate a tweet link: var link = '<a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(tweet) + '"></a>';

Comment: That's very close to what I'm doing and your jsfiddle shows £ and € signs correctly but when I run the same code in my JS file, I'm getting replacement characters in the alert. I can't demonstrate the problem in jsfiddle because it works there, there problem is with my local file - I suspect the JS file has incorrect character encoding but I don't know how to change it.